# Apache log RSA encryption

Tags: c, apache, encryption, rsa

I'm having trouble encrypting Apache logs. I want to encrypt the logs using OpenSSL EVP functions (i.e. using symmetric key wrapped inside an RSA public key), and encrypt streams of incoming logs to disk. To do this, I think I need to create a binary to encrypt logs from STDIN and redirect them to disk, by using the ErrorLog directive in Apache.

From another post, I think I have the encryption working. My encryption code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h> /* For htonl() */

int do_evp_seal(FILE *rsa_pkey_file, FILE *in_file, FILE *out_file)
{
    int retval = 0;
    RSA *rsa_pkey = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    unsigned char buffer_out[4096 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    size_t len;
    int len_out;
    unsigned char *ek = NULL;
    int eklen;
    uint32_t eklen_n;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    if (!PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(rsa_pkey_file, &rsa_pkey, NULL, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA Public Key File.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        retval = 2;
        goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa_pkey))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

    if (!EVP_SealInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), &ek, &eklen, iv, &pkey, 1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealInit: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    /* First we write out the encrypted key length, then the encrypted key,
     * then the iv (the IV length is fixed by the cipher we have chosen).
     */

    eklen_n = htonl(eklen);
    if (fwrite(&eklen_n, sizeof eklen_n, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fwrite(ek, eklen, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fwrite(iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_128_cbc()), 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }

    /* Now we process the input file and write the encrypted data to the
     * output file. */

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, in_file)) > 0)
    {
        if (!EVP_SealUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, buffer, len))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealUpdate: failed.\n");
            retval = 3;
            goto out_free;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
        {
            perror("output file");
            retval = 5;
            goto out_free;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(in_file))
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (!EVP_SealFinal(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealFinal: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }

    out_free:
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    free(ek);

    out:
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *rsa_pkey_file;
    int rv;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <PEM RSA Public Key File>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    rsa_pkey_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!rsa_pkey_file)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA Public Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    rv = do_evp_seal(rsa_pkey_file, stdin, stdout);

    fclose(rsa_pkey_file);
    return rv;
}
```

And decryption:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h> /* For htonl() */

int do_evp_unseal(FILE *rsa_pkey_file, FILE *in_file, FILE *out_file)
{
    int retval = 0;
    RSA *rsa_pkey = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    unsigned char buffer_out[4096 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    size_t len;
    int len_out;
    unsigned char *ek;
    unsigned int eklen;
    uint32_t eklen_n;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    if (!PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(rsa_pkey_file, &rsa_pkey, NULL, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA Private Key File.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        retval = 2;
        goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa_pkey))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

    /* First need to fetch the encrypted key length, encrypted key and IV */

    if (fread(&eklen_n, sizeof eklen_n, 1, in_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }
    eklen = ntohl(eklen_n);
    if (eklen > EVP_PKEY_size(pkey))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad encrypted key length (%u > %d)\n", eklen,
            EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fread(ek, eklen, 1, in_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fread(iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_128_cbc()), 1, in_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (!EVP_OpenInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), ek, eklen, iv, pkey))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_OpenInit: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, in_file)) > 0)
    {
        if (!EVP_OpenUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, buffer, len))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_OpenUpdate: failed.\n");
            retval = 3;
            goto out_free;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
        {
            perror("output file");
            retval = 5;
            goto out_free;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(in_file))
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (!EVP_OpenFinal(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealFinal: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }

    out_free:
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    free(ek);

    out:
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *rsa_pkey_file;
    int rv;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <PEM RSA Private Key File>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    rsa_pkey_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!rsa_pkey_file)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA Private Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    rv = do_evp_unseal(rsa_pkey_file, stdin, stdout);

    fclose(rsa_pkey_file);
    return rv;
}
```

The directive I have in Apache is:

```
ErrorLog "|/home/Desktop/encrypt /home/Desktop/public.pem > /home/Desktop/output.log"
```

But when I restart Apache and start to browse, the output.log file doesn't appear. Running the encryption function from a shell prompt produces results as expected.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this works OK from the command line, then the problem is probably that Apache doesn't have permission to write to your desktop.

From the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped):

> Piped log processes are spawned by the parent Apache httpd process, and inherit the userid of that process.

Try creating a subdirectory for the output.log file, and use `chown` to allow Apache to write to it.

Comment: Thanks - seemed to have done the trick! I have one other issue now, which might be better in another thread - but wondering if anyone knew here first. The output only appears in the file in 4096 byte chunks (presumably because of the buffer it reads in from STDIN). Is there any way to flush the output to the file so that it all gets output? I don't understand how to do it because the while loop needs to be an infinite loop to keep receiving input from STDIN...

Comment: @user4005750 That won't be possible if you're using a block cipher for encryption. You might have more luck with a stream cipher like RC4, but like you said, you would be better off asking about this in another thread.